# Azure DevOps release pipeline - define deployment group with variable ex.: Ubuntu-$(environment)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We want to use this release pipeline in all environments.

We have a few environments, each with the appropriate name: `Ubuntu-$(environment)`

Using `agentless job`, with `rest api` task `POST` method I call the corresponding URL: `https://org.visualstudio.com/project/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups`

It will create an `Ubuntu-$(environment)` which is an empty deployment group.

A terraform step will fill this deployment group in the next step.

After it a deployment group job need to run on the `Ubuntu-$(environment)` deployment group.

Is it possible to refer to it generically? Is there a workaround for this?
[image]

Of course, before I create the deployment group in the first step, I can't refer to it in subsequent deployment group jobs because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: Thank you, your reply helped me understand another direction. I was thinking unfortunately that the Deployment Group can only be hard coded into the release pipeline. I'm still waiting for 1-2 answers from others, maybe someone knows other practices.

Comment: I can fully understand your requirement. But there should be no method to achieve your needs in the Release Pipeline deployment group. Many users have the same requirement: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/variable-use-in-deployment-group-job/410295 But the suggestion ticket has been closed now.  I think it would be a good choice to open a new suggestion ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the Deployment Group name field doesn't support to use Pipeline Variable to define the name.

It currently only supports hard-coded deployment group name in Deployment Group job.

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.

For a workaround, you can consider changing to use the VM machine in the [YAML Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#target-an-environment-from-a-deployment-job).

```
variables:
  test: 123
stages:
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    # creates an environment if it doesn't exist
    environment: 
      name: $(test)
      resourceName: myVM
      resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello world
```

The Yaml Pipeline environment has the similar feature of the Deployment Group and it supports using Pipeline variable in name field.